# Azure Functions with SendGrid not compiling in Visual Studio

Tags: azure, azure-functions, sendgrid

I'm trying to get a simple example of Azure Functions using SendGrid in Visual Studio to run:

```
[FunctionName("SendEmail")]
public static void SendEmail([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = null)] [SendGrid()] out Mail message)
    {
        message = new Mail
        {
            Subject = "From VS"
        };

        var personalization = new Personalization();
        // change to email of recipient
        personalization.AddTo(new Email("joe@foo.com"));

        Content content = new Content
        {
            Type = "text/plain",
            Value = "testing from VS."
        };

        message.AddContent(content);
        message.AddPersonalization(personalization);
}
```

But I'm receiving the following compile error:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified.

Along with these warnings:
[image]

I have Visual Studio 2017 15.7.1 installed. The project is targeting .NET Standard 2.0 and my project has the following NuGet Packages installed:

[image]

What do I install or remove to allow this to compile?

Answer (score 1):

I observed the build warnings further below when referencing the **Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.SendGrid version 2.2.0** package because it is not compatible with .NET Standard. The warnings went away after upgrading the package to version 3.0.0-beta5. Moreover, please note this implies using a beta product, thoroughly test it before releasing any production code.

```
 1. 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.SendGrid 2.2.0' was restored   
    using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target  
    framework '.NETStandard,Version=v2.0'. This package may not be fully
    compatible with your project.
 2. 'Sendgrid 8.0.5' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1'
    instead of the project target framework '.NETStandard,Version=v2.0'.
    This package may not be fully compatible with your project.
 3. 'SendGrid.CSharp.HTTP.Client 3.0.0' was restored using
    '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target
    framework '.NETStandard,Version=v2.0'. This package may not be fully
    compatible with your project.
```

Comment: The removed the warnings and errors that I had before, but introduced a new set of errors. It appears Mail is not an object in SendGrid 3.0. I'm not sure the SendGridAttribute() has been updated to support.

Comment: Yes, it seems there are several breaking changes introduced by version 3.0.0-beta5. Here are the types to look into in the new version: SendGridClient, SendGridClientOptions and SendGridMessage.

Answer (score 1):

As Evandro Paula said, you could `Install-Package Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.SendGrid -Version 3.0.0-beta5` to let it compatible with .net standard.

Then, your script seems to be a mix of v1 and v2 functions. For example, `CreateResponse()` doesn't belong to `HttpRequest` and `Mail` class is not in `SendGrid` assembly.

Here is a very simplistic example of sending a mail from HTTP function:

```
public static IActionResult Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)]HttpRequest req, [SendGrid(ApiKey ="sendgridkey")] out SendGridMessage message, TraceWriter log)
        {
            log.Info("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            message = new SendGridMessage();
            message.AddTo("testto@gmail.com");
            message.AddContent("text/html", "Test body");
            message.SetFrom(new EmailAddress("testsend@gmail.com"));
            message.SetSubject("Subject");

            return new OkObjectResult("OK");
        }
```

Set the sendgridkey in your `local.setting.json` file:

```
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "storageconnectionstring",
    "AzureWebJobsDashboard": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "sendgridkey": "yoursendgridkey"
  }
}
```